# Compare two java property files using shell script

Tags: java, unix, shell

How to compare two property files in two different folders using shell script
input can be path of the two folders?

There are multiple files in both folders and each files needs to be checked

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably need to explain your requirements a bit more. However it's most likely you can do what you want with the diff command (with a little help from sort and/or grep).

Let's assume you have two files: a.properties and b.properties

If you simply want to know if the files are different in any way, you can use

```
diff a.properties b.properties
```

You'll get no output if they're identical or a list of differences.

If you want a comparison on a more semantic level, that is, are the two sets of properties identical, then you need to do a bit more. The files can differ textually, but mean the same thing to Java programs that use them. For example, the properties can occur in a different order. There can be blank lines, other whitespace and comments.

If this is the case, do you care if the comments are identical? They won't effect the operation of your program, but they have a meaning (and value to those reading the file). If you don't care, strip them out.

You probably don't care about blank lines as they have no meaning.

You also need to handle the following case:

```
a.properties:
    prop = value
b.properties:
    prop=value
```

Again, different textually (note the spaces around the equals) but have the same meaning in Java.

Starting simple, let's assume the properties occur in the same order.

Ignore blank lines:

```
diff -B a.properties b.properties
```

Handle random white space (eg. around the equals sign)

```
diff -w a.properties b.properties
```

Combine all of this:

```
diff -w -B a.properties b.properties
```

Strip out comments:

```
grep -v '^#.*$' a.properties > a.tmp
grep -v '^#.*$' b.properties > b.tmp
diff -w -B a.tmp b.tmp
rm a.tmp b.tmp
```

Allow for properties in a different order, strip comments:

```
grep -v '^#.*$' a.properties | sort > a.tmp
grep -v '^#.*$' b.properties | sort > b.tmp
diff -w -B a.tmp b.tmp
rm a.tmp b.tmp
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look into using diff or sdiff.  I would recommend sorting your files beforehand and removing any blank lines to reduce the amount of noise; e.g.

```
file1=/var/tmp/foo.txt
file2=/var/tmp/bar.txt

sort ${file1} | grep -v '^$' > ${file1}.tmp
sort ${file2} | grep -v '^$' > ${file2}.tmp
sdiff ${file1} ${file2}
```

Comment: @Adamski - what about comments in the property files?

Comment: this will show differences between comments as well

Comment: @StephenC - grep -vE "^$|^#" will work for you

Answer (score 3):

For semantic comparison, better use [PropDiff](http://www.baclace.net/java/prop_diff/index.html).

```
Usage: [flags] properties-file1 properties-file2 [-f filenameOrPathPrefixForResults]
   flags:
     -c  property settings that are common to both p1 and p2, where p2 take precedence
     -u  union p1 and p2 where p2 has higher precedence
     -1  properties settings that are only in p1
     -2  properties settings that are only in p2
     -d  intersection of properties in p1 and p2 that have different values
     -e  intersection of properties in p1 and p2 that have equal values
```

Answer (score 1):

[`comm`](http://bama.ua.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?comm) is a useful utility. It can tell you what's in file1 and not in file2, what's in file2 and not in file1, and what's common between the two files. It requires the two files to be sorted first.

I upvoted @antispams PropDiff answer since it seems to be exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use diff program, calling "diff /path/to/first/file /path/to/second/file" and cat a grep them. For special uses of diff (if you need anything special), try to search man diff.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want. Is a different comment a difference? Whitespace? Order? I think easiest would be a small groovy script. Is this an option? If no, make sure to strip comments abd whitespaces and sort the output before using `diff`

EDIT: while it's possible to let diff ignore whitespace, I'm not sure whether this is what you want as whitespace might be part of a properties value

Answer (score -1):

This Groovy allows you to diff two properties file.

You can pick 2 diff modes:
1. Show properties that are missing from one another
2. Compare the values to see similarity & differences

https://gist.github.com/aimtiaz11/f786346e0c0d11a5475cfb64e84e9459

Comment: please add relevant parts of your link here

Comment: Every part in that link is relevant. You will need to put the groovy script where the properties files are and then run it. The setup steps are detailed there along with the actual script.

Answer (score -2):

See another PHP code to diff properties files [on my blog](http://louise.hu/poet/?p=5336):

`php list_missing_properties.php "file1.properties" "file2.properties"`